# Android Accelerometer Reading

Tags: java, android, class, accelerometer

I want to use multiple classes to display Accelerometer readings. I have tried to get the accelerometer readings in a single class and it runs perfectly fine. 
But in this code the output is 0.00000 , 0.000000 , 0.00000

Here are my two classes:

```
package com.example.sample;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AccData accl=new AccData();     

    accl.mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accl.sensor = accl.mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    accl.register();
    String result=accl.getAccelerometerReading();
    TextView display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    display.setText(result);

}
}
```

2.

```
package com.example.sample;


import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class AccData extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {


public float acclX,acclY,acclZ;
public SensorManager mSensorManager;
public Sensor sensor;


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    acclX = event.values[0];
    acclY =event.values[1];
    acclZ = event.values[2];
    }

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void register() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
protected void unregister() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensor);
}
protected String getAccelerometerReading()
{
    return String.format("%7f" + ", %7f"+ ", %7f" ,acclX,acclY,acclZ);  
}
}
```

Comment: How do you update the content of the displayed textview? You are setting the content only **once** when the first activity is created.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But how do I update the content of the textview ?

Comment: And also through debugging I realized that the program control does not enter the onSensorChanged function

Comment: check this tutorial for android accelerometer data http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mechanism to inform other classes that `AccData` has updated values available. Typically, this is done by a listener - you already made use of this concept by this code line:

```
public class AccData extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
```

Your class `AccData` gets informed when there was a new SensorEvent.
More information on how to write listeners can be found at [this Java tutorials page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)

To give you a basic idea:

- Create an interface for the listener, e.g.

  ```
  public interface MyListener{
    public void processSensorEvent(SensorEvent event);
  }
  ```
- Add registerListener/ unregisterListener methods to the class `AccData`. Add also a data structure to store the registered listeners.
- Write a method `fireUpdate` in `AccData` that is called from within `onSensorChanged` and takes the new SensorEvent as argument.

  ```
  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    acclX = event.values[0];
    acclY =event.values[1];
    acclZ = event.values[2];
    fireUpdate(event);
  ```

  }
- The purpose of `fireUpdate` is to iterate over the list of registered listeners and call their implementation of the method `processSensorEvent(SensorEvent event)`

  ```
  private void fireUpdate(SensorEvent event){
    for (MyListener listener: MyListeners){
      listener.processSensorEvent(event);
    }
  }
  ```
- Let your main activity implement `MyListener`.

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyListener{
  ```
- Then you will have to implement the method `processSensorEvent(SensorEvent event)` in the main activity and can use it to update the textview.

  ```
  public void processSensorEvent(SensorEvent event){
    TextView display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    display.setText(event.values[0] + " " + event.values[1] + " " + event.values[2]);
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you specify which method should I use. I am a newbie in Android/Java programming.